# Azure Stream Analytics Query: Cast string to DateTime

Tags: azure, t-sql, datetime, azure-stream-analytics

The input of stream analytic is `IoT` hub and it will receive a `JSON` message as such.

**Data**:

```
[
   {
      "deviceId": "testing",
      "id": "b8db8f582c474225b90b75dfed2e9c63",
      "username": "testing",
      "localtime": "24/01/2018 11:31:24",
      "b": 240,
      "e": 357,
      "AC": 0,
      "FM": 0,
      "UC": 0,
      "DL": 0,
      "DS": 0,
      "DP": 0,
      "DR": 0,
      "LB": 120,
      "ASTV": 73,
      "MSTV": 0.5,
      "ALTV": 43
   }
]
```

In the `Azure Stream Analytics` query, I use `CAST` function to cast the localtime from string to datetime but it failed. It is not allowed to use `CONVERT` function.

```
SELECT
    id as id,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    username as username,
    cast(localtime as datetime) as localtime,
    AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, 
    DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP,
    LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV
FROM
    iot
```

> Cannot cast value '24/01/2018 12:58:23' to type 'datetime' in expression 'cast ( localtime as datetime )'

Comment: Are you try my updated answer? Is there any issue, write in the comments.

Comment: Try my updated Answer, Hope it works now...

Comment: The [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835052.aspx) was a supported `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `STRING FUNCTIONS`, we can achieve this:

And Azure Stream Analytics Supports the [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835052.aspx) Function.

```
SELECT
    id as id,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    username as username,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(localTime ,7 ,4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(localTime ,4 ,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(localTime ,1 ,2)+SUBSTRING(localTime ,11 ,9) AS DATETIME) as localtime,
    AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, 
    DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP,
    LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV
FROM
    iot;
```

Hope this will helps.

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @localTime VARCHAR(20)='24/01/2018 11:31:24'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@localTime ,7 ,4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@localTime ,4 ,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@localTime ,1 ,2)+SUBSTRING(@localTime ,11 ,9) AS DATETIME)
```

**Result:**

```
2018-01-24 11:31:24.000
```

Comment: CONVERT function is not allowed in stream analytics query. Stream analytics query language is just a subset of tsql. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn834998.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0

Comment: @SamTew, Are you try this?

Comment: Sorry for late trying as I am busy with other things. Again, there is an error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKQ3F.png

Comment: I think the error was not for the `SUBSTRING` function, it's because of the `nvarchar(max)` of your Datatype. Can you please change the datatype to `NVARCHAR(100)` or something, and try this. Hope that gives you the result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that the `localtime` "24/01/2018 12:58:23" has DD/MM/YYYY format and your job uses the locale that expects MM/DD/YYYY, so the issue is that there is no month 24.

You can either change the locale of your job or use [JavaScript function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) to parse datetime with a specific locale.